# Website already has SSL certificate, I want to use CloudFront CDN with SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I already have a `https://` website which has an SSL certificate from COMODO RSA.

I want to start putting videos onto cloudfront to speed up their delivery.

When I do this i'm prompted with a 'Request an ACM certificate' button, which when clicked says I need to add an SSL certificate for my website.

If I add this certificate is it going to break anything? As I'll therefore have 2 SSL certificates - I'm confused.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You typically can't have two certificates for the same site *from the same Certificate Authority*, but that isn't applicable here -- AWS has their own CA, which of course is not the same CA as Comodo.

Adding a certificate in ACM won't hurt anything, but it's arguably unnecessary -- if you already have a certificate and the accompanying intermediate chain and key, you can [upload it to IAM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html) and use it in CloudFront.

However, unless the certificate you already have is particularly valuable -- such as an EV certificate (which costs several hundred USD per year and puts your corporate name and country in green in the browser's address bar), or provides you with some kind of liability protection (some SSL CAs throw in such guarantees, depending on the certification level) then creating a new cert with ACM will be the easiest solution -- they're easy to obtain, renew themselves, and are provided without cost.

If you're not familiar with how to work with SSL certificates, going with ACM will be the path of least resistance, and again, shouldn't hurt anything.